# How to activate a touchscreen device without human interaction

Tags: capacitor, touchscreen

I need to be able to activate apps on my iPad without human interaction. We have tried dropping batteries onto the screen but that only works if dropped within a few inches. Is there any material in existence that can activate a touchscreen without human involvement, nor through the use of a stylus?

Comment: How about an alarm? Though, admittedly, a human is involved in setting the alarm.

Comment: You'll have to give far more information as to your goal and your limitations. Ideally, this would easily be solved by software. If you must get into hardware, I would wonder how much control do you need?

Comment: ... Why can't you use a robot-operated stylus?

Comment: (Which seems to explain why.)

Comment: Can you call in C3PO or R2D2?

Comment: I am just a noob..but samsung uses eye movement for same  http://abcnews.go.com/Technology/samsung-eye-mouse-lets-users-control-computer-blink/story?id=27168677

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how permanent this needs to be, a hotdog, sausage, SlimJim, or cheese stick can work. You could even wrap it in a ziplock bag to prevent juices from touching.

Comment: We tried these things. They don't work unless a human is holding them. If they are dropped onto the screen, they do not open the app

Comment: This is for a high school engineer student